# UNION ALL records less than sum of individual queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I use `UNION ALL` to merge results from 3 queries. But I notice that total number of records returned by `UNION ALL` query is less than the sum of results returned by the individual queries.
I know `UNION` removes the duplicates, but why is count different even in case of `UNION ALL`.

I am trying this out in `MS Access 2010` itself.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you show the actual query?

Comment: If you are unioning 3 queries, you have 2 `UNION` keywords. Perhaps one of them is `UNION ALL` and the other `UNION`?

Comment: When I tried the same this again now, the count seems to match. Not sure whether it is my carelessness or application is behaving erratically. Anyway thanks for inputs.

Comment: @user2413045 Don't forget to close your question in order to remove it from the unanswered list